# ImageButton and ImageView not showing in custom dialog (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android

In my to-do list app project, I wanted to create a bottom sheet. For some reason, my ImageButton and ImageView are not showing up after running the app.

Here is my xml file for the bottomsheat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rouned_corners_dialog"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="373dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/arrowbtn_bottomsheet"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/newtask_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/create_new_task_txt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/task_name"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/task_name"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#757575" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/task_location"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/Location"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#757575" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/task_date"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:text="@string/mm_dd_year"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#757575"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cancel_btn_bottomsheet"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.068"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cancel_btn" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_task_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_task_btn_bottomsheet"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.931"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/addtask_btn" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9noqs.png]

And this is the java code

```
 ImageButton add_list_button1=findViewById(R.id.addlistbtn);
        add_list_button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                add_list_bottomsheet=new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.bottom_sheet_theme);
                View sheetview= LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_list_bottomsheet, null);

                sheetview.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        add_list_bottomsheet.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                add_list_bottomsheet.setContentView(sheetview);
                add_list_bottomsheet.show();

            }
        });
```

this is the output

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJTLs.png]

Tried looking for similar problems in the net but haven't found any luck

Comment: You are missing constraints for the inner constraint layout. Also the outer constraint  layout's height should be "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent" so that the bottom sheet is as high as its content.

Comment: what should my constraints be for my inner constraint layout?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that your root layout is a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ConstraintLayout`. Chaning the `layout_height` of both the `ConstraintLayout` and `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml try changing the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of the root linear layout and constraint layout. Also set the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` of the constraint layout.